# InvalidSessionIdException: Message: Session does not exist error while using Switch Application keyword in Robot Framework with Appium library

Tags: ios, robotframework, appium-ios, ios-ui-automation, python-appium

I'm facing issue while switching to same application on different devices.
At first occasion switch is working fine but second time it's failing and giving below error:

**InvalidSessionIdException: Message: Session does not exist**

```
Open Application on first device    alias=A
Open Application on second device   alias=B
Switch Application    A
Performing some activity on first device
Switch Application    B
Performing some activity on second device
Switch Application    A
Last step: Performing some activity on first device
```

Here, error is occurring at last step: '`Last step: Performing some activity on first device`'

Run report:

[image]

iOS version on both real devices is: 13.6

Can someone guide here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by setting different wdaLocalPort for the first and second device.

[image]

https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver